# SignalR OnConnected() method is called regardless of Authorize attribute

Tags: authorization, signalr, asp.net-identity, signalr-hub

I'm new to SignalR.  I'm learning to use SignalR, so far it seems really great.

I'm just trying to get my head around restricting the connections to authorized (logged in) users as I'm already using ASP.NET Identity Framework.

I have my `[Authorize]` attribute on my hub, but that isn't stopping my `OnConnected()` method from being called when a connection attempt is attempted by a non-authorized user.

I have attempted to implement `PersistentConnection` and override the AuthorizeRequest method like so, I thought that this might solve it:

```
namespace Common.Connections
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Authorizes requests for persistent connections in SignalR
    /// </summary>
    public class AuthenticatedConnection : PersistentConnection
    {
        protected override bool AuthorizeRequest(IRequest request)
        {
            return request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe that isn't supposed to stop the method being called.

I guess that I could easily just check for authorization manually within my `OnConnected()` method, but I'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

Is the `OnConnected()` method supposed to be called for non-authorized connection attempts?

Comment: Are you sure you are using [Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.signalr.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) instead of something else like [System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)? If so, `OnConnected` should not be called unless `IRequest.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true. Can you provide your Hub code?

Comment: Have you found reason? I have the same problem and I user signalR authorize attribute.

Comment: I suspect that @halter73 is correct on this one, the Authorize attribute will need to come from the correct namespace.